# In aws-cli, how to delete items from DynamoDB based on a condition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, conditional-statements, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I'm using AWS CLI and having issues deleting rows based on a condition

I have a file_name key and I'd like to remove all keys containing "20200322".

Command

```
aws dynamodb delete-item \
    --table-name "logs" \
    --condition-expression "contains(file_name, :file_name)" \
    --expression-attribute-names file://expression.json \
    --key file://key.json
```

expression.json - the variables to use in the contains

```
{
    ":file_name": {
        "S": "20200322"
    }
}
```

key.json - I don't understand the point of this file

```
{
    "file_name": {
        "S": "20200322"
    }
}
```

Error

> Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter
>   ExpressionAttributeNames.:file_name, value: OrderedDict([(u'S',
>   u'20200322')]), type: , valid types:

Questions

- How do I delete a single entry based on a contains condition?
- Why is the key mandatory if I'm using the `--expression-attribute-names` switch? What does the key need to be?
- What is the difference between `--expression-attribute-values` and `--expression-attribute-names`

Reference

- [DynamoDB > Condition Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html)
- [DynamoDB > API_DeleteItem_RequestSyntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html#API_DeleteItem_RequestSyntax)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`contains` function takes 2 parameter: a `path` and the `operand`

> contains (path, operand)

Here you're missing the operand.

```
aws dynamodb delete-item \
    --table-name "logs" \
    --key '{"file_name": {"S": "20200322"}}'
    --condition-expression "contains(file_name, :file_name)" \
    --expression-attribute-values file://wvid_logs.json
```

**Note** there is double quotes within a pair of single quote.

and in the JSON should be something like

```
{
    ":file_name": {
        "S": "20200322"
    }
}
```

The thing is that you want to run a conditional delete, so the key needs to be the key of your item you want to delete, and the expression attribute values will be the condition to check, I am not fully sure you can run a condition on the key itself.

Lets suppose you have

```
{
    "Id": {
        "N": "12345"
    }
    "file_name": {
        "S": "20200322"
    }
}
```

running the command

```
aws dynamodb delete-item \
    --table-name "logs" \
    --key '{"Id": {"N": "12345"}}'
    --condition-expression "contains(file_name, :file_name)" \
    --expression-attribute-values file://wvid_logs.json
```

The command will delete the item only when the condition from the file matches the item. so if in file you have

```
{
    ":file_name": {
        "S": "20200322"
    }
}
```

It will delete the item, any other value in your JSON file will not delete the item.

Comment: Hi @frédéric-henri, you're right, I wasn't using `--expression-attribute-values`. I was using `--key` instead. I updated the command I'm running above and have a new error. I'm unsure the point of `--key` if I'm using the expressed values.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in my case I found (after a long while) that the key property (and all map properties) should be enclosed in single quotes when input directly in the terminal

```
aws dynamodb delete-item \
    --table-name "logs" \
    --condition-expression "contains(file_name, :file_name)" \
    --expression-attribute-names file://expression.json \
    --key '{":file_name": {"S": "20200322"}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on windows with powershell. in the end i resorted to this for a string id:

```
aws dynamodb delete-item --key '{""user_id"":{ ""S"":""myuserid""}}' --table-name users --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```